# CakePHP - Remove asterisk from required inputs

Tags: cakephp

I'm building a CakePHP application that involves forms, and I'm looking for a way to remove the asterisk from required fields.  I have several input fields that are required, but I do not want the asterisk to show.

I've tried using `'required'=>false`, but that makes the field optional as well as removing the asterisk.  I just want to remove the asterisk; the field needs to remain required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could modify the css that adds that. I've made changes in my css, so I'm not sure if it's the one that comes out of the box anymore (for that matter, I don't know if *you* are using the one that comes out of the box), but the css that adds those asterisk(s?) on my form is

```
label.required:after {
    color: #EE3322;
    content: "*";
    display: inline;
}
```

And you should just replace that `content:"*"` with

```
content: "";
```

Now, if your css isn't the same as mine, inspect the label element, and look for a similar line (it's probably using a `content: "*"`, so you know what you have to look for).

If you want to delete the asterisks for a single view, add an inline style in the view. If it is for the whole application, delete the line in the css file.